# Pivot Tables with "ValueError: cannot label index with a null key"

Tags: pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby

I am given a dataframe called items_by_creation_date, as follows.

```
   itemid  item_creation_date
0         1925574 2015-10-01 00:24:42
1         1925617 2015-10-01 00:26:37
2          943600 2015-08-25 21:02:13
3         1064405 2015-08-30 20:16:07
4        20046620 2016-05-09 01:14:34
5        20047128 2016-05-09 01:18:21
6        78419076 2016-10-20 11:17:41
7       252736983 2017-05-09 18:33:30
8       793229430 2017-12-28 19:55:45
9       809446063 2018-01-05 16:08:24
```

I will like to find out how many items are created in 2018, and I planned to start by creating a pivot table with "itemid" as the index.

```
items_by_creation_date.pivot(index = "itemid", values = "item_creation_date")
```

However, it returns me the following error:

> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
>   line 3852, in get
>       raise ValueError("cannot label index with a null key") ValueError: cannot label index with a null key

I have been stuck for 2 days on this error! Can any kind soul please enlighten me on what caused the error, and how do I actually fix the problem?

Other things I tried: (but failed to work)

```
items_by_creation_date = data.groupby(["itemid"]["item_creation_date"].apply(list))

items_by_creation_date.assign(Count = items_by_creation_date.groupby('itemid').cumcount()).pivot("itemid")
```

If you can think of a better way method to find out how many items are created in 2018, please share it here as well! I greatly appreciate all your advice.

Best Regards,

Bangwu

Comment: how do you want the output to look like?

Comment: `df[df['item_creation_date'].dt.year==2018].shape[0]` ?

Comment: Hello Vivek, thanks for your response! I wanted to make sure each itemid has an unique item_creation_date, so a df with ['itemid']['item_creation_date'] will be great

Comment: Vivek, I tried your code above, but I get a error saying that "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime'"